# Fade-transitioning effect for background images - overlapping issue

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, keyframe

**AIM**

I would like to show a faded transition among three pictures *(ideally 10, I used three for this question)*. Each image should gradually increase its opacity until fully opaque and then the next picture should start the same process, i.e. starting from opacity 0 to 1.

**PROBLEM**

If you have a look at the snippet, you'd see that only the third image follows this opacity process while the first two are vaguely shown as the first image overlaps them.

Thanks for your help!

**ATTEMPT**

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  
  .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-1 {
  background-image: url("https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/23/2019/10/Federico_Veronesi_Lions-cover-image-e359a4e.jpg?quality=45&crop=10px,234px,3691px,2458px&resize=620,413");
  animation: fade1 10s infinite;
}
.slide-2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490100886609-e401a775fb3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
  animation: fade2 10s infinite;
}
.slide-3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  animation: fade3 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide-1"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS animation is doable but requires some kind of trick. The reason why your code does not work is because **all the CSS animations are happening at the same time**. What you want is to ensure that fade1, fade2, and fade3 all start and stop at consecutive intervals, so that they will come after each other:

- fade1 starts at 0% and ends at 33% (1/3)
- fade2 starts at 33% (1/3) and ends at 67% (2/3)
- fade3 starts at 67% (2/3) and ends at 100% (3/3)

Of course, this means that you will need to (1) declare a new keyframe for each slide added and (2) adjust the start/end points of *all* keyframes when a new slide is added. This can be cumbersome, and the only way to automate this (or do it programmatically) is to use JS or preprocessed CSS.

See proof-of-concept below:

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  
  .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-1 {
  background-image: url("https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/23/2019/10/Federico_Veronesi_Lions-cover-image-e359a4e.jpg?quality=45&crop=10px,234px,3691px,2458px&resize=620,413");
  animation: fade1 10s infinite;
}
.slide-2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490100886609-e401a775fb3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80");
  animation: fade2 10s infinite;
}
.slide-3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  animation: fade3 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  67% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  67% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide-1"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
</body>
```

---

### SCSS solution

If you are using a CSS preprocessor such as SCSS, you can simply generate slides on the fly: all you need is to remember to add the corresponding markup:

```
// Just some demo images
$images: [
  'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/3077FF/fff?text=Slide1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/2C9EE8/fff?text=Slide2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/3DE4FF/fff?text=Slide3',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/2CE8CE/fff?text=Slide4',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/30FFA8/fff?text=Slide5',
];

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

@for $i from 1 through length($images) {
    $image: nth($images, $i);

    // Custom animation styles and background image for each slide
    .slide-#{$i} {
      animation: fade#{$i} 10s infinite;
      background-image: url(#{$image});
    }

    // Generate keyframe for each slide
    @keyframes fade#{$i} {
      #{(($i - 1) / length($images)) * 100%} {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      #{($i / length($images)) * 100%} {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
}
```

See example below (the CSS has been precompiled):

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-1 {
  animation: fade1 10s infinite;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/3077FF/fff?text=Slide1);
}

@keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slide-2 {
  animation: fade2 10s infinite;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/2C9EE8/fff?text=Slide2);
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slide-3 {
  animation: fade3 10s infinite;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/3DE4FF/fff?text=Slide3);
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slide-4 {
  animation: fade4 10s infinite;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/2CE8CE/fff?text=Slide4);
}

@keyframes fade4 {
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slide-5 {
  animation: fade5 10s infinite;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/30FFA8/fff?text=Slide5);
}

@keyframes fade5 {
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide-1"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-4"></div>
    <div class="slide slide-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly the result I wanted! Thank you! Would you mind showing how it could be done using JavaScript or jQuery? A link you might know of would also be useful.

Comment: @Joehat I've added a SCSS example. For a JS-based example, there are plenty of slider/gallery plugins out there, and there is also a lot of code on StackOverflow that you can already reuse and repurpose.

Comment: For the SCSS version, is there a way of preventing the blank background when the loop re-starts?

Comment: could you please give me any advice on the width and height of *.slide*? I first had ```width: 100%; height: 100%```, all of my project is already responsive but I noticed that the content of the page containing *.slide* wasn't. I believe it was because of the 100%. I noticed this issue when opening the responsive tool of my browser. It's OK on desktop but not on smaller screens. Media queries are being ignored only in this page containing the slide animation...

Comment: When I manually adjust the screen size with the responsive tool, media-queries work fine. When I click for instance on iPhone X it does not. I opened the website on my phone and it was assuming it was a desktop screen as media queries once again were being ignored. Once again, this only happens on this page. I use mixins for media-queries so there are no typos there... Hoping you could help so I know what exactly might be causing this...

Answer (score 1):

To do a faded transition you need to add percentages to the keyframes. This depicts the percentage of time you would like the image to appear on screen.
For this example you picked three so it would be 100/3 which unfortunately is 33.33333(you get the idea.)

Anyway, here's the updated keyframes for your three images. To adjust these over 10 images you would simply need to 100/10 (10% for each image).

All should start with opacity 0 at 0% then opacity 0 at the starting percentage(in the first image's case it's 33%. Then 0 opacity at 100%.

```
    @keyframes fade1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  66% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

If you would like further explanation let me know.